# SQL query for this combined expected results - pivot?

Tags: sql, database

Sorry for this long winded question, but I'm not sure how to go about constructing this SQL query needed for the results I want.  I'll outline the two queries that I currently run and work fine and I will outline the results I need.  Any help will be appreciated.

1st Query:

```
SELECT c.name AS name, count(*) AS total, sum(a.views) AS total_views, sum(a.views) / count(*) as average_views
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b ON b.id = a.b_id
JOIN table_c c ON c.id = b.c_id
WHERE a.status = 0 AND a.type in (2, 4, 5)
GROUP BY c.name ORDER BY c.name;
```

Result:

```
--------------------------------------------
name | total | total_views | average_views |
--------------------------------------------
aaaa |     2 |         150 |            75 |
bbbb |     1 |          75 |            75 |
dddd |     1 |          25 |            25 |
--------------------------------------------
```

2nd query:

```
SELECT c.name AS name, count(*) AS total, sum(a.views) AS total_views, sum(a.views) / count(*) as average_views
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b ON b.id = a.b_id
JOIN table_c c ON c.id = b.c_id
WHERE a.status = 0 AND a.type in (1, 3)
GROUP BY c.name ORDER BY c.name;
```

2nd results:

```
--------------------------------------------
name | total | total_views | average_views |
--------------------------------------------
aaaa |     2 |         200 |           100 |
bbbb |     1 |         100 |           100 |
dddd |     1 |          25 |            25 |
--------------------------------------------
```

Given these tables with this data:
Table table_a:

```
-----------------------------------
id | b_id | views | type | status |
-----------------------------------
 1 |  100 |   100 |    2 |      0 |
 2 |  200 |    75 |    4 |      0 |
 3 |  300 |    50 |    5 |      0 |
 4 |  400 |    25 |    2 |      0 |
 5 |  500 |   100 |    1 |      0 |
 6 |  600 |   100 |    1 |      0 |
 7 |  700 |   100 |    3 |      0 |
 8 |  800 |    25 |    3 |      0 |
-----------------------------------
```

Table table_b:

```
-------------
id  | c_id  |
-------------
100 |  1000 |
200 |  2000 |
300 |  1000 |
400 |  4000 |
500 |  1000 |
600 |  2000 |
700 |  4000 |
800 |  1000 |
-------------
```

Table table_c:

```
-------------
id   | name |
-------------
1000 | aaaa |
2000 | bbbb |
3000 | cccc |
4000 | dddd |
-------------
```

This is the table that I actually want, which is simply a concantenation of the above two tables with the common column being the name column.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
name | total_type245 | total_views_type245 | average_views_type245 | total_type13 | total_views_type13 | average_views_type13 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
aaaa |             2 |                 150 |                    75 |            2 |                200 |                  100 |
bbbb |             1 |                  75 |                    75 |            1 |                100 |                  100 |
dddd |             1 |                  25 |                    25 |            1 |                 25 |                   25 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It's most likely quite a simple query, but I cannot work out how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: You can make inner join on both query.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aa1d5/2 test here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just join the results together;

```
SELECT ResultsA.name, 
total_type245, 
total_views_type245, 
average_views_type245,
total_type13,
total_views_type13,
average_views_type13

FROM
(
    SELECT c.name AS name, count(*) AS total_type245, sum(a.views) AS total_views_type245, sum(a.views) / count(*) as average_views_type245
    FROM table_a a
    JOIN table_b b ON b.id = a.b_id
    JOIN table_c c ON c.id = b.c_id
    WHERE a.status = 0 AND a.type in (2, 4, 5)
    GROUP BY name

) as ResultsA

JOIN 
(
    SELECT c.name AS name, count(*) AS total_type13, sum(a.views) AS total_views_type13, sum(a.views) / count(*) as average_views_type13
    FROM table_a a
    JOIN table_b b ON b.id = a.b_id
    JOIN table_c c ON c.id = b.c_id
    WHERE a.status = 0 AND a.type in (1, 3)
    GROUP BY name

) as ResultsB ON ResultsA.name = ResultsB.name

ORDER BY ResultsA.name
```

Comment: Matt,

Thanks, that does work, but just to throw a spanner in the works, what if there is a mismatch between the name columns - i.e., the name columns may be different for each result, and therefore if there is no result for a name, then that column should be 0?

Thanks to BeNdErR above for the SQL executor app, see here for what I mean: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/b819b/1  There should be a row for the name eeeee, but it doesn't output.

Comment: Ok, you just start by selecting the names directly from table c, and then left joining the results to that.  See <http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b819b/1> - note that this is running under MySQL, it was throwing a weird exception in Postgres, and I don't know enough about postgres to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so with Matt's help this query works:

```
SELECT c.name, total_type245, total_views_type245, average_views_type245, total_type13, total_views_type13, average_views_type13
FROM table_c c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT c.name AS name, count(*) AS total_type245, sum(a.views) AS total_views_type245, sum(a.views) / count(*) as average_views_type245
    FROM table_a a
    JOIN table_b b ON b.id = a.b_id
    JOIN table_c c ON c.id = b.c_id
    WHERE a.status = 0 AND a.type in (2, 4, 5)
    GROUP BY name
) as ResultsA ON ResultsA.name = c.name
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT c.name AS name, count(*) AS total_type13, sum(a.views) AS total_views_type13, sum(a.views) / count(*) as average_views_type13
    FROM table_a a
    JOIN table_b b ON b.id = a.b_id
    JOIN table_c c ON c.id = b.c_id
    WHERE a.status = 0 AND a.type in (1, 3)
    GROUP BY name
) as ResultsB ON ResultsB.name = c.name;
```

Is this the most efficient query for the job though?  It seems I'm repeating lots of the query with the only change being the a.type value being the difference.